# Adding multiple cardviews

Tags: android

I am trying to have dynamic number of cardviews in my layout.For test i am trying to insert 3 cardviews in my layout,but instead of three only one card is added with "hello 3" written on it.
Here's my code for activity.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    int i;
    LinearLayout layout=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.mainl);

    for(i=1;i<=3;i++)
    {
        setContentView(R.layout.card);
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater=(LayoutInflater) getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        final View addView=layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.card,null);
        TextView t=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.text1);
        t.setText("hello "+String.valueOf(i));
        layout.addView(addView);

    }

}
```

}
`

code for cardlayout

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
android:id="@+id/cardv"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_height="50dp"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_margin="10dp"
card_view:cardCornerRadius="10dp">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="25dp"
    android:text="Hello"
    android:layout_gravity="center"/>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

For contentmain

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:id="@+id/mainl">

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because in loop cycle, you set content view each loop.
Please just remove this line setContentView(R.layout.card);
So your onCreate() method will look like this:

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    int i;
    LinearLayout layout=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.mainl);

    for(i=1;i<=3;i++)
    {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater=(LayoutInflater) getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        final View addView=layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.card,null);
        TextView t=(TextView) addView.findViewById(R.id.text1);
        t.setText("hello "+String.valueOf(i));
        layout.addView(addView);

    }

}
```